# validation form using Spring 3

Tags: spring, validation

i'm creating validation form on Spring 3, My problem is, that i saw a lot of examples with validation form. I even created one. but my form passing "result.hasErrors()" method, even when there are errors.

My code is:

Controller:

> 

```
package com.esb.sso;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import javax.servlet.http.*;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import com.esb.sso.form.LoginForm;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class HomeController {

LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();

        model.put("loginForm", loginForm);

        return "home";
    }


@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String validation(@Valid LoginForm loginForm, BindingResult result,
        Map model) throws IOException {

    logger.info("Login POST var");

    logger.info(loginForm.getLogin());
    logger.info(loginForm.getPassword());

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        logger.info("error");
        return "home";
    }

    model.put("loginForm", loginForm);

    return "logged";

}

}
```

Validator:

> package com.esb.sso.form;

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class LoginForm {

    @NotNull(message = "notNull")
    @Size(min=1, max=50, message="mote charters")
    private String login;

    @NotNull(message = "notNull")
    @Size(min=1, max=50, message="mote charters")
    private String password;

    public void setLogin(String login){
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getLogin(){
        return login;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password){
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPassword(){
        return password;
    }


}
```

View:

> 

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
Autoryzacja!!!
<form:form action="" commandName="loginForm">

<table>

<tr>

<td>User Name:<FONT color="red"><form:errors path="login" /></FONT></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td><form:input path="login" /></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>Password:<FONT color="red"><form:errors path="password" /></FONT></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td><form:password path="password" /></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>

</tr>

</table>

</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml:

> 

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

servlet-context:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.esb.sso" />

    <beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <beans:property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

and messages.properties:

```
    NotNull.loginForm.login=must not be blank.
NotNull.loginForm.password=must not be blank.
Size.loginForm.login=Login size must be between 1 and 50 charters.
Size.loginForm.password=Password size must be between 1 and 50 charters.
```

**I don't know where is the problem**

Coul'd enybody help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming copy paste error in HomeController-get method of the "/" mapping method.

To answer your question - You must specify the LoginForm object as model attribute in order to bind validations on it with BindingResult. Below is the correct code

```
public String validation((@ModelAttribute("loginForm") @Valid LoginForm loginForm, BindingResult result, 
        Map model) throws IOException {
```

For reference see the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-arguments)

Comment: i've added @ModelAttribute, but this nothing changed. I still don't have correct validation. :(

Comment: Can you try '@NotEmpty' annotation from Hibernate validator(hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA.jar) instead of '@NotNull'. Actually it may be because 'form:input' tag submits value of an empty string when you don't specify any input thereby passing @NotNull validation.

Comment: This change did nothing. My project was based on 'http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/spring/spring3/web/spring-3-mvc-validation-example.html' . When i download that example, it works correct. But when i trying bo build it by my own, or just copy files to new project from that example, the form is not validating. I mean, that the validation is not working. Every form is passed by the validation. Maybe i should try other example ?